# Local browserstack serenity testing

Tags: maven, browserstack, serenity-bdd

I am trying to run a serenity test locally via browserstack. I have downloaded the following test repo: https://github.com/browserstack/serenity-browserstack

replaced my browserstack credentials and run the following command mvn clean verify -P local.

I am using the browserstack chrome extension on my mac but whenever i use the command nothing happens, there is no activity on the remote browser screen.

And when looking in browserstack Automate tab i see that a test has been run but the local is false...

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable local testing BS Automate needs [this](https://github.com/browserstack/serenity-browserstack/blob/master/serenity.properties#L25) capability as well as their BrowserStackLocal binary should be up and running before the test executes.

I see that their code starts the BrowserStackLocal binary programmatically (replacement of chrome extension) before test begins.

- https://github.com/browserstack/serenity-browserstack/blob/master/src/test/java/com/browserstack/BrowserStackSerenityTest.java#L39

Do verify that the '**browserstack.local**' capability is correctly set to '**True**'. This should enable the local testing and use the binary connection which is being spawned by above code.

P.S : Chrome's BS local extension wont be used by BS Automate, it is used only by BS Live.

Comment: Using the binary has given me the following error: com.browserstack.local.LocalException: Either another browserstack local client is running on your machine or some server is listening on port 45691

Comment: after some experimentation i have succeeded to call browserstack via BrowserStackSerenityTestL39 but when i look in browserstack "Local Testing" is still false... so i have added the following args.

bsLocal = new Local();
Map<String, String> bsLocalArgs = new HashMap<String, String>();
bsLocalArgs.put("key", accessKey);
bsLocalArgs.put("v", "true");
bsLocalArgs.put("force", "true");
bsLocalArgs.put("forcelocal", "true");
System.out.println(bsLocalArgs.values());
bsLocal.start(bsLocalArgs);

But sadly no change

Comment: I see that you were able to run the binary. Now ensure that your script sets  'browserstack.local' capability to true. https://github.com/browserstack/serenity-browserstack/blob/master/serenity.properties#L25 is how the cap is configured in the example.

Comment: removing the ".replace("browserstack.", "")" from the following line: https://github.com/browserstack/serenity-browserstack/blob/master/src/test/java/com/browserstack/BrowserStackSerenityDriver.java#L43 made it work... seems that this might be a bug as the other browserstack properties are now not readable. Thanks for the help :)